# Question about IDEs is missing in questionnaire

Tags: bug, survey-2017

There is a questionnaire provided with [the last survey results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/). It's great but I can't find there the question about IDEs.  But there is such column in the data file.
How this question was formulated? What conditions did it have? And was there any "other" field for a free form answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that, the question got removed from the published instrument by mistake.  We'll update the PDF as soon as we can; for now, here are the response options for the question.

> Which development environment(s) do you use regularly? Please select all that apply.
>
> - Android Studio
> - Atom
> - Coda
> - Eclipse
> - Emacs
> - IntelliJ
> - IPython/Jupyter
> - Komodo
> - Light Table
> - NetBeans
> - Notepad++
> - PHPStorm
> - PyCharm
> - RStudio
> - RubyMine
> - Sublime Text
> - TextMate
> - Vim
> - Visual Studio
> - Visual Studio Code
> - Xcode
> - Zend
> - Other (please specify)

We did not include the "other" write-ins for this Q (or any other) in the public results file because some respondents wrote in rather *odd* things in those fields, including information that could be used to identify some of them.

Comment: Thank you. It would be great thou if you replace all "other" write-ins with some keyword ("other" for example). So it would be possible to distinguish "other" and non-response.